# How to link Sitecore 9.2 and SOLR running on Azure App service

Tags: solr, azure, sitecore-install-framework

I have installed SOLR 7.5 on Azure App service and this SOLR instance is running fine.

Now I have installed Sitecore 9.2 through Azure Sitecore marketplace and mentioned this SOLR url as a search provider.
My Sitecore 9.2 installed successfully and its running fine.

But on my SOLR, none of the Sitecore indexes are created. 
Also in Sitecore control panel, my indexing manager not showing any indexes.

Do anybody guide here how to install SOLR 7.5 on Azure App service and link it with Sitecore 9.2?
Do I need to create SOLR indexes manually on Azure App service? How to do it SOLR on Azure App?

Comment: This project was specifically designed for this very issue: https://github.com/jraps20/Solr-AzureAppService/tree/Sitecore . It would only take you a few minutes to redo it all with the one-click deploy button.

Comment: @jrap - I guess OP is saying that SOLR app service is setup correctly , but on provisioning Sitecore from Azure Marketplace , Sitecore does not create Indexes automatically in the new App Service. 
I think I need to check the ARM templates and see if it possible to edit and insert the same functionality as SIF scripts

Comment: The answer is in there. I’ll write up a better answer today.

Comment: @jrap .. I have installed SOLR from the same URL that you shared https://github.com/jraps20/Solr-AzureAppService/tree/Sitecore . My SOLR instance is running fine. But my question is How to create indexes on SOLR for Sitecore 9.2 as Sitecore installation didn't created these indexes.

Comment: If you used the Sitecore branch of the repo then it should have created them for you. I have tested this approach on 9.2. I will review further in a few hours.

Comment: @jrap ... any luck on Sitecore and SOLR index on Azure App?

Comment: I just checked my logs. Its an connectivity issue. I am getting HTTP ERROR 404 on my Sitecore App service for SOLR. My Sitecore and SOLR app is running on DIFFERENT resource Group. 
Do anybody know how to provide access for SOLR running on App service of one resource group to Sitecore running on app service of another resource group on Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create all the cores locally and then upload the cores through FTP link in the Deployment center. Once uploaded, restart the Solr App service. Then you can go to the Sitecore Control Panel and populate the Solr schema and subsequently re-index.

Comment: Hi sumit, what should be the name of core folders as my Sitecore azure instance name is something like "xyz-66853.azure.com"?

Comment: names can be sitecore_core_* , similar to sitecore naming conventions , check your index names from /admin/showconfig.aspx and edit if required

Comment: yes, names can be as per your choice but if you choose any name other than the default sitecore ones then you would have to update it in the corresponding config.

Answer (score 2):

Per comment discussion, the OP leveraged this repository: https://github.com/jraps20/Solr-AzureAppService/tree/Sitecore

> Note: This repo intentionally comes in two flavors: Solr (master branch) and Sitecore Solr (Sitecore branch).

The Sitecore branch is designed to install the necessary Solr cores for a new Sitecore installation. It was intentionally designed to work with the Azure Marketplace Sitecore Cloud resource.

After Solr is installed, the script `Deploy-SolrAzureAppService.ps1` is executed. This script is responsible for creating the Solr cores:

1. Downloads requested Solr version set in one-click deployment properties to the web app root
2. Copies native Solr config set (either `_default` or `basic_configs` based on Solr version) as `sitecore` config set, to be referenced by each Sitecore Solr core config properties.
3. Modifies the `conf\managed-schema` of the `sitecore` config set with required Sitecore updates

   1. Updates `<uniqueKey>` element
   2. Adds `<field name="_uniqueid"... />` to schema
4. Creates all Sitecore cores referencing `sitecore` config set

   1. sitecore_analytics_index
   2. sitecore_core_index
   3. sitecore_fxm_master_index
   4. sitecore_fxm_web_index
   5. sitecore_list_index
   6. sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master
   7. sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web
   8. sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master
   9. sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web
   10. sitecore_master_index
   11. sitecore_suggested_test_index
   12. sitecore_testing_index
   13. sitecore_web_index
   14. social_messages_master
   15. social_messages_web
5. Creates xDB cores referencing native config set (`_default` or `basic_configs`)

   1. xdb
   2. xdb_rebuild

Once completed, you should see all cores in Solr. You can verify this prior to installing Sitecore from Azure.

When creating Sitecore from Azure, when it asks for the Solr URL, the format is like this: `https://myappservice.dev.azure.net/solr` (i.e. the same URL you use to view the Solr instance)

The question mentions that Solr is already up and running, and while you could upload the cores via FTP or leverage the Kudu tool, it would be much quicker to remove the existing app service and then redo the installation with the same app service name. My hunch is that you used the non-Sitecore version originally and that is why no cores are present.

Comment: ..I just checked my logs. I think its a connectivity issue. I am getting HTTP ERROR 404 on my Sitecore App service while connecting to SOLR. My Sitecore and SOLR app is running on DIFFERENT resource Group. Do you know how to provide access for SOLR running on App service of one resource group to Sitecore running on app service of another resource group on Azure?

Comment: It shouldn't be dependent on resource groups. Can you visit Solr from a public URL? I would check the `ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress` you have defined in your Sitecore configs.

Comment: I can access SOLR on a public URL and I used the same public SOLR URL while installing Sitecore

Comment: There is no such "ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress" setting in SItecore config. I think you are pointing towards "solr.search" in connectionstring.config file.

Comment: Very informative post @jrap - It looks like spinning up a basic azure app service would be around $55/month ($0.07/hour) whereas a single node on SearchStax for a dev instance is only $20/month so that might be something to keep in mind if you don't need complete control over the service.

Comment: @BenSewards with this (https://github.com/jraps20/jrap-AzureVerticalScaling) you can "turn off"/i.e. make it free when you're not using it. So take that $55/mo and assume you need it "on" for 8hrs/24hrs... which leads to $18.33/mo. Also, since I hop around while developing I typically set up a webhook to turn it on as-needed (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#:~:text=From%20the%20Runbooks%20page%20in,open%20the%20Create%20Webhook%20page.) and then rely on the auto-shutdown at 5pm, for example.